# Check that an input is a Date Java

Tags: java

Hi is there a way to check if an input is a date in Java, the date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` so `int\int\int`
I have the basic check `if (x != "")` but I was wondering if you check that it is a date.

Now I'me getting a new error code:

```
try {
      date = (Date) dateFormat.parse(dateInput);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
                System.out.println("FAIL!!!!!!!!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date entered is incorrect, please close this window and try again");
                new BookApp();
            }
```

The indents probably got messed in when I copied and pasted it, but when the format is wrong it works and the dialog menu pops up. But when I give `12\08\2015`  it give a `ClassCastError`.
How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a formatter for your date pattern :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

2) Try to format your String input to a date :

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse(input);
```

Now, if the input doesn't match your pattern, you get a ParseException.

Comment: and change MMM to MM

Comment: Today was hard, thanks for correcting me twice :)

Comment: hi when I add `12/08/1998` for instance it throws a `ClassCastException` but the format is correct, any idea how to stop this?

Comment: This is another problem, you should post your code if you need to be helped on this

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to parse the date and capture if the parse was successful or not.

The [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will throw an exception if the string was not parsable as a date.

```
public boolean isDate(String dateString) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return dateFormat.parse(dateString) != null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```